# Error in my header file - error: 'QSMatrix' does not name a type, how do I fix this issue?

Tags: c++

I have two classes, one of which is declared as a friend class. I am trying to write a function in my first class that uses my second class but I get this error:

> error: 'QSMatrix' does not name a type

Here is my .h file:

```
#include <vector>

#ifndef LSM_H
#define LSM_H

class LSM {
public:
    // Overload Constructor
    LSM(const double, const double, const double, const int, const int, const double, const double, const int, const int);

    // Destructor
    ~LSM();

    // Print contents of vector
    void print(std::vector<double>);

    // Generate the Laguerre Polynomials
    QSMatrix<double> Laguerre(int, std::vector<double>);


    // Generate M paths of stock prices (Geometric Brownian Motion)
    std::vector<double> GBM(const int, const int, const double, const double, const double, const double, const double);

    // Payoff of call option
    std::vector<double> callPayoff(std::vector<double>, const double);

private:
    // Member variables
    double new_r;
    double new_q;
    double new_sigma;
    int new_T;
    int new_N;
    double new_K;
    double new_S0;
    int new_M;
    int new_R;
};

//////////////////////////////// Used Matrix Class From Quant Start /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

template <typename T> class QSMatrix {
    friend class LSM;
 private:
  std::vector<std::vector<T> > mat;
  unsigned rows;
  unsigned cols;

 public:
  QSMatrix(unsigned _rows, unsigned _cols, const T& _initial);
  QSMatrix(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs);
  virtual ~QSMatrix();

  // Operator overloading, for "standard" mathematical matrix operations
  QSMatrix<T>& operator=(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs);

  // Matrix mathematical operations
  QSMatrix<T> operator+(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs);
  QSMatrix<T>& operator+=(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs);
  QSMatrix<T> operator-(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs);
  QSMatrix<T>& operator-=(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs);
  QSMatrix<T> operator*(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs);
  QSMatrix<T>& operator*=(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs);
  QSMatrix<T> transpose();

  // Matrix/scalar operations
  QSMatrix<T> operator+(const T& rhs);
  QSMatrix<T> operator-(const T& rhs);
  QSMatrix<T> operator*(const T& rhs);
  QSMatrix<T> operator/(const T& rhs);

  // Matrix/vector operations
  std::vector<T> operator*(const std::vector<T>& rhs);
  std::vector<T> diag_vec();

  // Access the individual elements
  T& operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col);
  const T& operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col) const;

  // Access the row and column sizes
  unsigned get_rows() const;
  unsigned get_cols() const;

  // Print the matrix
  void print() const;

};

#endif
```

Here is the associate .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "LSM.h"


LSM::LSM( const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const int T, const int N, const double K, const double S0, const int M, const int R){
    new_r = r;
    new_q = q;
    new_sigma = sigma;
    new_T = T;
    new_N = N;
    new_K = K;
    new_S0 = S0;
    new_M = M;
    new_R = R;

/*
    std::vector<double> v;
    v = GBM(new_M, new_N, new_T, new_r, new_q, new_sigma, new_S0);

    QSMatrix<double> A(2,2,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            A(i,j) = 1;
        }
    }
    A.print();
*/

    std::vector<double> V;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        V.push_back(rand());
        std::cout << V[i] << std::endl;
    }



}

LSM::~LSM(){

}

void LSM::print(std::vector<double> vector){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
        std::cout << vector[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

std::vector<double> LSM::callPayoff(std::vector<double> S, const double K){
    std::vector<double> V;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++){
        if(S[i] - K > 0){
            V.push_back(S[i] - K);
        } else {
            V.push_back(0.0);
        }
    }
    return V;
}

std::vector<double> LSM::GBM(const int M, const int N, const double T, const double r, const double q, const double sigma, const double S0){
    double dt =  T/N;
    std::vector<double> Z;
    std::vector<double> S;
    S.push_back(S0);
    std::mt19937 e2(time(0));
    std::normal_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        Z.push_back(dist(e2));
    }
    double drift  = exp(dt*(r-0.5*sigma*sigma));
    double vol = sqrt(sigma*sigma*dt);
    for(int i = 1; i < M; i++){
        S.push_back(S[i-1] * drift * exp(vol*Z[i]));
    }
    return S;
}



QSMatrix<double> LSM::Laguerre(const int R, std::vector<double> X){
    int n = X.size();
    int m = R + 1;
    QSMatrix<double> poly(n,m,0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            if (R == 1){
                poly(i,0) = 1.0;
                poly(i,1) = -X[i] + 1.0;
            }
            else if (R == 2){
                poly(i,0) = 1.0;
                poly(i,1) = -X[i] + 1;
                poly(i,2) = 0.5 * (2.0 - 4.0*X[i] + X[i]*X[i]);
            }
            else if (R == 3){
                poly(i,0) = 1.0;
                poly(i,1) = -X[i] + 1;
                poly(i,2) = 0.5 * (2.0 - 4.0*X[i] + X[i]*X[i]);
                poly(i,3) = 1.0/6.0 * (6.0 - 18.0*X[i] + 9.0*X[i]*X[i] - X[i]*X[i]*X[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return poly;
}

//////////////////////////////// Used Matrix Class From Quant Start /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Parameter Constructor
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T>::QSMatrix(unsigned _rows, unsigned _cols, const T& _initial) {
  mat.resize(_rows);
  for (unsigned i=0; i<mat.size(); i++) {
    mat[i].resize(_cols, _initial);
  }
  rows = _rows;
  cols = _cols;
}

// Copy Constructor
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T>::QSMatrix(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs) {
  mat = rhs.mat;
  rows = rhs.get_rows();
  cols = rhs.get_cols();
}

// (Virtual) Destructor
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T>::~QSMatrix() {}

// Assignment Operator
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T>& QSMatrix<T>::operator=(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs) {
  if (&rhs == this)
    return *this;

  unsigned new_rows = rhs.get_rows();
  unsigned new_cols = rhs.get_cols();

  mat.resize(new_rows);
  for (unsigned i=0; i<mat.size(); i++) {
    mat[i].resize(new_cols);
  }

  for (unsigned i=0; i<new_rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<new_cols; j++) {
      mat[i][j] = rhs(i, j);
    }
  }
  rows = new_rows;
  cols = new_cols;

  return *this;
}

// Addition of two matrices
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T> QSMatrix<T>::operator+(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs) {
  QSMatrix result(rows, cols, 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      result(i,j) = this->mat[i][j] + rhs(i,j);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Cumulative addition of this matrix and another
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T>& QSMatrix<T>::operator+=(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs) {
  unsigned rows = rhs.get_rows();
  unsigned cols = rhs.get_cols();

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      this->mat[i][j] += rhs(i,j);
    }
  }

  return *this;
}

// Subtraction of this matrix and another
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T> QSMatrix<T>::operator-(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs) {
  unsigned rows = rhs.get_rows();
  unsigned cols = rhs.get_cols();
  QSMatrix result(rows, cols, 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      result(i,j) = this->mat[i][j] - rhs(i,j);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Cumulative subtraction of this matrix and another
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T>& QSMatrix<T>::operator-=(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs) {
  unsigned rows = rhs.get_rows();
  unsigned cols = rhs.get_cols();

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      this->mat[i][j] -= rhs(i,j);
    }
  }

  return *this;
}

// Left multiplication of this matrix and another
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T> QSMatrix<T>::operator*(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs) {

  QSMatrix result(rows, rhs.get_cols(), 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<rhs.get_cols(); j++) {
      for (unsigned k=0; k<cols; k++) {
        result(i,j) += this->mat[i][k] * rhs(k,j);
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Cumulative left multiplication of this matrix and another
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T>& QSMatrix<T>::operator*=(const QSMatrix<T>& rhs) {
  QSMatrix result = (*this) * rhs;
  (*this) = result;
  return *this;
}

// Calculate a transpose of this matrix
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T> QSMatrix<T>::transpose() {
  QSMatrix result(cols, rows, 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<cols; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<rows; j++) {
      result(i,j) = this->mat[j][i];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Matrix/scalar addition
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T> QSMatrix<T>::operator+(const T& rhs) {
  QSMatrix result(rows, cols, 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      result(i,j) = this->mat[i][j] + rhs;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Matrix/scalar subtraction
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T> QSMatrix<T>::operator-(const T& rhs) {
  QSMatrix result(rows, cols, 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      result(i,j) = this->mat[i][j] - rhs;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Matrix/scalar multiplication
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T> QSMatrix<T>::operator*(const T& rhs) {
  QSMatrix result(rows, cols, 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      result(i,j) = this->mat[i][j] * rhs;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Matrix/scalar division
template<typename T>
QSMatrix<T> QSMatrix<T>::operator/(const T& rhs) {
  QSMatrix result(rows, cols, 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      result(i,j) = this->mat[i][j] / rhs;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Multiply a matrix with a vector
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> QSMatrix<T>::operator*(const std::vector<T>& rhs) {
  std::vector<T> result(rhs.size(), 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    for (unsigned j=0; j<cols; j++) {
      result[i] = this->mat[i][j] * rhs[j];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// Obtain a vector of the diagonal elements
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> QSMatrix<T>::diag_vec() {
  std::vector<T> result(rows, 0.0);

  for (unsigned i=0; i<rows; i++) {
    result[i] = this->mat[i][i];
  }

  return result;
}

// Access the individual elements
template<typename T>
T& QSMatrix<T>::operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col) {
  return this->mat[row][col];
}

// Access the individual elements (const)
template<typename T>
const T& QSMatrix<T>::operator()(const unsigned& row, const unsigned& col) const {
  return this->mat[row][col];
}

// Get the number of rows of the matrix
template<typename T>
unsigned QSMatrix<T>::get_rows() const {
  return this->rows;
}

// Get the number of columns of the matrix
template<typename T>
unsigned QSMatrix<T>::get_cols() const {
  return this->cols;
}

// Print the content of the matrix
template<typename T>
void QSMatrix<T>::print() const {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            std::cout << this->mat[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

What is the correct or the best way to do it?

Comment: You probably need to `#include` the header file containing the declaration of `QSMatrix`. None of the headers you're currently including would contain such a type.

Comment: Is `QSMatrix` declared at the point of `QSMatrix<double> Laguerre(int, std::vector<double>);` in the header file? From what can I see - it is not. So move `QSMatrix` before the definition of `LSM`, so it would be declared.

Comment: Did you include your my.h file where your class is defined in the associated.cpp file? I do not see it included in your example.

Comment: @Jonesinator His header, **does** contain the definition of `QSMatrix`.

Comment: Oops, yeah. See @AlgirdasPreidžius comment.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I do that in the header file?

Comment: @Wolfy Yes. It is one of the ways you can solve this issue with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Algirdas Preidžius mentioned: when you define templates, you write all the definitions in the header file.